# Conditionally apply CSS class to wtforms element in Python flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I want to apply an additional **is-invalid** CSS class to a wtforms element only if there is an error present in the form.

I've landed on the following code to achieve this and it works:

```
{% if form.email.errors %}
{{ form.email(placeholder="Email", class="form-control is-invalid") }}
{% else %}
{{ form.email(placeholder="Email", class="form-control") }}
{% endif %}
```

However, it's not very consise and i'm having to repease the whole form.email element. This could get real messy if the logic was more complicated.

There must be a cleaner way to have only the class value wrapped in logic.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the string concatenation operator "~" with an inline if statement, e.g.

```
{{ form.email(placeholder="Email", class="form-control" ~ " is-invalid" if form.email.errors else "") }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [jinja macros](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#macros).  In your template you can put this and then modify the logic if you're looking to expand things.

```
{% macro render_email_field(field) %}
    {% if field.errors %}
        {{ field(placeholder="Email", class="form-control is-invalid") }}
    {% else %}
        {{ field(placeholder="Email", class="form-control") }}
    {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}

{{ render_email_field(form.email) }}
```

You can also put macros into a separate file and bring them into a particular template with

```
{% from "_jinja_macros.html" import render_email_field %}
```